# Lenovo power supply

Tags: power-supply, lenovo-laptop

I have two Lenovo laptops and I can't remember which power supply adapter goes to which.
One power adapter output is 20V and 2.25 amps, the other is 20V and 3.25 amps.
If I were to switch the power adapters, how much trouble might it cause?

Comment: I assume that the 2.25 amp might under power the 3.25 amp laptop, but the 3.25 amp power supply won't hurt the other laptop too much.

Comment: The expected voltage and current should be labelled on the laptops too. And you also have to watch the polarity. Your assumption in the comment is correct - more supply current won't do anything (the required current is pulled by the load, and no more), but a lower supply current than required can lead to overheating of the supply.

Answer (score 3):

I have long experience with IBM and Lenovo laptops.

You can use any genuine Lenovo adapter with any Lenovo laptop with same socket with no damage to laptop or power supply. **In Lenovo - if you can plug it in - it will work.**

If you have powerful laptop (with dedicated GPU and fast CPU) - you may be not able to charge battery with 45W charger (2.25A) when laptop is turned on.

Here is lenovo shop link to 45W (2.25A) adapter: [link](http://shop.lenovo.com/ca/en/itemdetails/0B47030/460/FB655FA7A2834E04AED9731463CD174E)

Page under that link says:

> ### ThinkPad 45W AC Adapter (Slim Tip)
>
> - Compatible with ThinkPad Helix, T4301s, and 2013 Lenovo notebooks with slim common power plug
> - Not compatible with legacy notebook systems with the round, barrel-type power plug

Comment: From experience, any lenovo power supply with the right tips work - there's usually a 'regular'/travel varient and a 'quickcharge' varient, both of which work with the same models and differ with size. There also seem to be official 'standard' to 'slim' tip converters as well. So yeah, this seems tight